# Updating multiple rows for user - Setting 1 row as "Default" Yes, and other to be No

Tags: c#, sql, .net-framework-version

Lets assume the following data selected from SQL TBL_Profiles:

| No | User | Profile | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | Profile1 | Yes |
| 2 | User1 | Profile2 | No |
| 3 | User1 | Profile3 | No |

Currently, User1 default profile is Profile1. That's how it was setup initially when profiles were created. If User1 decided at a later stage to change his/her default profile, that means the newly selected profile should update Default = Yes, and the rest update Default = No. I can do that by selecting all profiles, iterate then update. However, I'm looking more into the easiest concept to do so. Hope I'm clear (which I doubt, since the idea is still vague in my little brain).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this data structure, it's better to hold 1 foreign key "Default Profile" in some upper lever table (perhaps in Users table).

But anyway, if you must apply multiple changes, I suggest to execute an SQL update statement, like this:

```sql
UPDATE  TBL_Profiles
SET     [Default] = CASE WHEN T.[Profile] = @SelectedProfile THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM    TBL_Profiles AS T
WHERE   T.[User] = @User
```

and don't forget to pass the 2 parameters @User and @SelectedProfile

let me know if it answers your question, or if it needs some adjustments

Comment: Amazing what lack of sleep can do to us. I mean the first part of the answer was obvious and I couldn't think of it. Yet I'm glad I asked, and got three answers in one. To me, the SQL statement is epic. Can be done from C# or as a stored procedure. Very grateful mate

Comment: happy to assist :)

Comment: I would probably add `AND [Default] <> CASE WHEN T.[Profile] = @SelectedProfile THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` in the `WHERE`